# script inclusion in joomla 3

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla3.1

I've written a little jquery code to scroll some div content on a joomla 2.5 site.
It works well on that site.

I am now attempting to add it to a new joomla 3.1 template, based on the protostar template.

when included DIRECTLY in the head - it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> CODE </script>
```

When I attempt to include it from its folder - not working :[

the call i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/js/div_scroller.js"></script>
```

script is named "div_scroller.js", and is in the JS folder of my template.

the output of that call is:

```
<script src="/Vcore/templates/vcoretemplate/js/div_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Vcore is the root folder. "vcoretemplate" is my template name (and folder).

I have no clue why this doesn't work.

**important note:** the original was in a production environment - in a LINUX server. this runs on my local WAMP server - windows. Perhaps this is the problem?

If so, how do I make the same link in the head tag work for both operating systems?

Thank you!

the script itself, if relevant:

```
 //this script scrolls the content of all divs with class .scrolling

jQuery("document").ready(function(){

//set document css for scrolling
  var elem= jQuery("div.scrolling div").first();
  var cont=jQuery(elem).parent().height();


 //scrollspeed heigher is SLOWER
  var scrollspeed=115;

   jQuery(elem).parent().css("height",cont).css("overflow","hidden");
   jQuery(elem).css("margin-top",cont+10);



//call the scroller


scrollnews(elem,cont,scrollspeed);
setInterval( function() { scrollnews(elem,cont,scrollspeed); }, cont*scrollspeed+100);

});



function scrollnews(elem,cont,scrollspeed){

        jQuery(elem).animate({marginTop:-cont-10},cont*scrollspeed,"linear", function(){

        jQuery(elem).css("margin-top",cont+10);

        });
}
```

Comment: is it showing any error on console when you use as external file ?are you included jquery library  before that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following to include the JS file which is Joomla coding standards:

```
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'templates/vcoretemplate/js/div_scroller.js');
```

or the traditional **JDocument** method:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JUri::root() . 'templates/vcoretemplate/js/div_scroller.js');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In the end, this worked:
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ($this->baseurl)?>/templates/<?php echo($this->template)?>/js/div_scroller.js"></script>


but i think there was some error with the file. i made a new one iwth the same content and it worked. Thank you for your help and time!